# XQuery - How to enable sql:variable to keep decimal places

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to keep the decimal places of whole numbers when values are retrieved from an XQuery sql:variable function.

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @variableName DECIMAL(16,2) = 123.00;
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Test/SubTest/text())[1] with sql:variable("@variableName")');
```

Result:

```
<Test>
     <SubTest> 123 </SubTest>
</Test>
```

Desired Result:

```
<Test>
     <SubTest> 123.00 </SubTest>
</Test>
```

What are the changes I need to make to get the desired result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `decimal` to `nvarchar` prior to use `XQuery`.

```
    DECLARE @xml xml = '<Test>A</Test>', @variableName DECIMAL(16,2) = 123.00, @str nvarchar(max)
SET @str = Convert(nvarchar(max), @variableName)
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Test/text())[1] with sql:variable("@str")');
SELECT @Xml, @str
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin function fn:format-number helps you formatting your numbers in the way you desire:

```
format-number(123, "000.00")
```

which gives:

```
replace value of (/Test/SubTest/text())[1]
with format-number(sql:variable("@variableName"), "000.00")
```

Comment: Hi @Ghuslain , I am getting 'There is no function .. ' error when I try the above.

Comment: Hi juniordeveloper87, you may need to explicitly add the fn: prefix in front of format-number, depending on your configuration.

Comment: I'm afraid that SQL server (if this is what you are using) is not implementing the latest XQuery function library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Hi @Ghilsain, thanks for your input. Think that explains why it didnt work just now. :(